# recommendation for IAM for .NET Core with row level security

Tags: security, asp.net

I am looking for a good IAM library or framework for .NET Core that would give row level filtering of a SQL data set. Are there any out of the box solutions that would support something similar to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120639/entity-level-access-control-in-a-hierarchical-data-scheme

Are the any recommendations?